# Which sense of the phrase “to be in” is used here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: Hu Tao]

> **Hu Tao**: A satisfying *trade* to *be in*, though, and Wangsheng Funeral Parlor is well-known around town. Whatever the request, I’d be glad to hear it.
>
> <sub>from [the YouTube video “Hu Tao wants to sell you coffins (Genshin Impact)”](https://youtu.be/oodGL_Ll41U?t=155)</sub>

What does “*trade* to *be in*” mean?

---

#### “To be in” <sub>https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+in</sub>

1. To be found or located inside some place or thing.
2. To be involved in or a part of something.
3. To be willing to become involved in or contribute to something.
4. To be currently (and usually temporarily) fashionable or trendy.
5. To be in an elected position.
6. To be inside a particular place.
7. To be in close association with someone or some group. In this usage, the phrase is usually accompanied by “with.”
8. To anticipate or be very likely to experience something, usually that which will be unpleasant or undesirable. In this usage, the phrase is usually accompanied by “for.”
9. To be involved with or a part of something for a particular reason or purpose. More usually “be in it for.”
10. To be in prison or similarly detained for a particular reason. In this usage, the phrase is usually accompanied by “for.”
11. To be participating or involved in something, often something secret or exclusive. In this usage, the phrase is usually accompanied by “on.”

Comment: Do you know what "trade" means in that sentence?

Comment: @ColleenV I’m not sure about it too. Does the “trade” mean “a skilled job, typically one requiring manual skills and special training” (the Google dictionary) in this sentence?

Comment: It will make it easier to choose the correct definition of "to be in" if you understand how "trade" is being used first. You may want to edit your question to explain what you guess "trade" means and only include the definitions of "to be in" that you think are possible. For example, "to be in an elected position" is obviously not correct for this context. Which definitions do you think fit?

Comment: @ColleenV The only definition I knew of the noun “trade” was “a commercial transaction,” which confused me. Now that I’ve learned that it can also mean “a commercial business,” I understood what she meant by “satisfying to be in.” Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's #9. She's in the funeral parlor business (trade = business). Apparently, she wants to sell the other character a coffin.

Comment: I see, she meant “It’s a satisfying business for me to work in (‘to be part of’).” Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.